# How to show boot text instead of the splash or blank screen on Ubuntu/Kubuntu 18.04?

Tags: boot, grub2, nvidia, bootloader, grub-efi

Editing kernel parameters and removing 'quiet' and 'splash' doesn't bring loading text - I continue seeing black screen with no text. Pressing ESC doesn't magically show anything either. The first thing which is displayed  so far - SDDM login screen (Kubuntu here).

`/etc/default/grub` contents:

```
$ cat /etc/default/grub
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"


I'm not sure which version of GRUB should I report, so instead I'll just list all the GRUB packages that are installed:
```

- **grub-common** 2.02-2ubuntu8.7
- **grub-efi-amd64** 2.02-2ubuntu8.7
- **grub-efi-amd64-bin** 2.02-2ubuntu8.7
- **grub-efi-amd64-signed** 1.93.8+2.02-2ubuntu8.7
- **grub2-common** 2.02-2ubuntu8.7

Also if it matters:

- Video card: nVidia GeForce 980 GTX Ti
- Video driver: proprietary version 410
- Kernel: 4.15.0-39

Comment: It might help seeing `/etc/default/grub` contents. Also mention if you ran `sudo update-grub` after changing the file.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix sorry, I should have shared it (updated). I didn't change this file yet - I only edited kernel parameters online when booting.

Comment: You could try: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nosplash"` which is subtly different but it might not help. It's could be an issue with video driver on boot and you might need to use: `GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480` or some derivative of it.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to removing quiet splash from GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT
Uncomment (remove #) from the line: #GRUB_TERMINAL=console.

```
sudo update-grub
```

and reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text package installed.
Check if you have it using `dpkg -s plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text|grep Status`.
If exists remove it by `apt-get remove plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text`.